# Remove extra white spaces from the json

Tags: java, json, parsing

In Java I have a json string and I want to remove the extra white spaces from it. I don't want to remove the space from the character in keys and values.

Actual JSON string

```
{ "Error" : "Invalid HTTP Method" , "ErrorCode" : "405" , "ErrorDesc" : "Method Not Allowed" }
```

Required JSON

```
{"Error":"Invalid HTTP Method","ErrorCode":"405","ErrorDesc":"Method Not Allowed"}
```

Comment: why? what possible use would that be?

Comment: so you want to minify it?

Comment: I want to compare this json with the other json. But because of the extra space I am not able to compare.

Comment: You should not compare it at the string level, anyway. Read the string as a Java object and compare it to the other Java object.

Comment: Parse both the JSONs and compare them. Avoid such manipulations.

Comment: Comparing json objects as strings is doomed in any case, since json objects do not have a defined order of fields.  `{"a":1,"b":2}` equals `{"b":2,"a":1}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I´d go with something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{ \"Error\": \"Inv\\\"alid HTTP Method\", \"ErrorCode\":\"405\",\"ErrorDesc\":\"Method Not Allowed\"}";

    System.out.println(removeWhitespaces(json));
}

public static String removeWhitespaces(String json) {

    boolean quoted = false;
    boolean escaped = false;
    String out = "";

    for(Character c : json.toCharArray()) {

        if(escaped) {
            out += c;
            escaped = false;
            continue;
        }

        if(c == '"') {
            quoted = !quoted;
        } else if(c == '\\') {
            escaped = true;
        }

        if(c == ' ' &! quoted) {
            continue;
        }

        out += c;

    }

    return out;

}
```

Testrun returns

```
{"Error":"Invalid HTTP Method","ErrorCode":"405","ErrorDesc":"Method Not Allowed"}
```

Comment: Be careful parsing the string yourself like this, because it will fail if there is a quote mark embedded within a string, which _can_ happen. In JS this will create a failure case: `let myjsonstr = '{"Error" : "Invalid Method", "ErrorCode" : 405, "ErrMsg" : "This \\\"Thing\\\" is not allowed" }';` Something like this can just as easily be created in Java, or when read from a database or typed by a user.

Comment: @StephenP true, thanks for pointing it out. Adjusted the answer

Comment:  that will take care of the escaped-quote `\"` case but opens up a whole other can of worms; parsing is not easy.  What happens if you encounter `\t` in a string? What about `\\t` or, like I used `\\\"`? Many things have special meaning when escaped with a backslash and it's not just "print the char following the backslash" — e.g. `\t` should be turned into a tab character `0x09`. You can be safe using your method if you have a limited and known set of inputs, and that is probably the OPs case, but future readers may try to extrapolate this to a general case and that's why I pointed it out.

Comment: @StephenP yep, should be pointed out for the further readers, anyways the scope was to replace whitespaces. It will not parse \t in any way but it also does not get lost which means the Deserializer in the end should still be able to parse everything correctly I guess

Answer (score 11):

An even simpler an safer solution would be to use the **Gson library** (Only a few lines needed):

```
public static String simplify(String json) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    JsonElement el = JsonParser.parseString(json);
    return gson.toJson(el);
}
```

and you can even reverse the entire process (**adding spaces**) with Gson's pretty printing option:

```
public static String beautify(String json) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    JsonElement el = JsonParser.parseString(json);
    return gson.toJson(el);
}
```

Hope this will help you

You get the latest version from here:
[Gson Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

Comment: Note that this solution might change content of data a little bit. For example, keys with null values seem to be filtered from the output. This might or might not be acceptable, but anyway it should be pointed out in the answer text!

Answer (score 1):

What @Fabian Z said would probably work, but could be optimized (You don't need to convert the entire String to a char array first to iterate it and you should also use a StringBuilder):

```
public static String removeWhitespaces(String json) {
    boolean quoted = false;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    int len = json.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = json.charAt(i);
        if (c == '\"')
            quoted = !quoted;

        if (quoted || !Character.isWhitespace(c))
            builder.append(c);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Also when using

```
Character.isWhitespace(c)
```

it will also remove line breaks

Comment: Have you ever benchmarked this ? I´m just curious if/when it gets more expensive to use charAt(i) compared to Enumeration.

Comment: No I didn't benchmarked this, but how would you use an Enumaration on a String? I guess even JsonParser will read the chars one after another. What you could do to improve this by a lot is to tell the StringBuilder the capacity it needs to be. Just pass it json.length() in the StringBuilder's constructor. For all I know, this should be a pretty efficient implementation. What would you change to make it faster?

Comment: Also as @Andrei Kovrov mentioned you should also take escaped quotes into account. But you should defenetly tell the StringBuilder / StringBuffer in its constructor about the json's length.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about escaped quotes `\"`!

```
static String minimize(String input){
     StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();    
     boolean qouteOpened = false;
     boolean wasEscaped = false;
     for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++){
         char c = input.charAt(i);
         if (c == '\\') {
            wasEscaped = true;
         }
         if(c == '"') {
             qouteOpened = wasEscaped ? qouteOpened : !qouteOpened;
         }
         if(!qouteOpened && (c == ' ')){
             continue;
         }
         if (c != '\\') {
            wasEscaped = false;
         }
         strBuffer.append(c);
     }
     return strBuffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JsonWriter to create that Json code, you could do

```
jsonWriter.setIndent("");
```

to remove all whitespaces in json code (Tested with Gson's Json Writer)

Comment: I have a org.JSONObject and I am converting this to a string. At the time of conversion I am trying to remove the extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is probably my final answer to this post:

```
public static CharSequence removeWhitespaces(CharSequence json) {
    int len = json.length();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(len);

    boolean escaped = false, quoted = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = json.charAt(i);
        if (c == '\"') {
            if (!escaped) quoted = !quoted;
            else escaped = false;
        } else if (quoted && c == '\\') {
            escaped = true;
        }

        if (quoted || c != ' ') {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }

    return builder;
}
```

Or if you want to assure that you got rid of all whitespace characters then use:

```
public static CharSequence removeWhitespaces(CharSequence json) {
    int len = json.length();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(len);

    boolean escaped = false, quoted = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = json.charAt(i);
        if (c == '\"') {
            if (!escaped) quoted = !quoted;
            else escaped = false;
        } else if (quoted && c == '\\') {
            escaped = true;
        }

        if (quoted || !Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }

    return builder;
}
```

This method is way more efficient than to first convert the string into a Json structure and back to a string, because that would be way to time consuming.

Telling the StringBuilder in advance which start capacity it should have also speeds up the process by a lot, if you have a long input String.
(Capacity is not equals to length, meaning that even if you tell the StringBuilder eg. it should have a capacity of 100 it will still only have a length of the text you put into it)

**And since StringBuilder implements CharSequence you can directly return the entire StringBuilder instead of converting it back to a String. But if you need a String and not a CharSequence, just call builder.toString(); at the end of this method and set the return type to String.**